# How to make OwningRef work with iterators?

Tags: rust, iterator, borrow-checker, ownership, petgraph

I have a `RwLock` protected global `WORLD`, and I want to write a function that read locks it and returns an iterator (of type `Neighbors`) that iterates over edges in a `petgraph::stable_graph::StableGraph` that is stored inside the global. I'm using `OwningRef` to deal with keeping the read lock guard alive after the function exits, which has worked for me in the past when just returning a field of `World` directly. I've included a compilable example and the error I'm getting below -- it seems there is some sort of type problem but I haven't been able to figure it out. I think it might have to do with `OwningRef` wanting to deal with a reference rather than an object containing a reference (`Neighbors`) but I'm not sure how to work around that.

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "problem_demo"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Joseph Garvin <joseph.h.garvin@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
owning_ref="0.4.1"
once_cell="1.4.0"
petgraph={version="0.5.1", features=["serde-1"]}
```

main.rs:

```
use std::{sync::RwLock};
use once_cell::sync::OnceCell;
use owning_ref::RwLockReadGuardRef;
use petgraph::stable_graph::{StableGraph, Neighbors};

struct Bar {
    data: i32
}

struct World {
    graph: StableGraph<(), Bar, petgraph::Directed, u32>
}

pub static WORLD: OnceCell<RwLock<World>> = OnceCell::new();

fn neighbors(id: u32) -> Result<RwLockReadGuardRef<'static, World, Neighbors<'static, Bar, u32>>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    RwLockReadGuardRef::new(WORLD.get().unwrap().read().unwrap())
        .try_map(
            |world: &World| -> std::result::Result<Neighbors<'static, Bar, u32>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>
            {
                let neighbors = world.graph.neighbors_directed(
                    petgraph::graph::NodeIndex::new(id as usize),
                    petgraph::Direction::Outgoing
                );

                Ok(neighbors)
            }
        )
}
```

Errors:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `for<'r> <[closure@src/main.rs:21:13: 29:14 id:_] as std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r World,)>>::Output == std::result::Result<&'r _, _>`
  --> src/main.rs:20:10
   |
20 |         .try_map(
   |          ^^^^^^^ expected struct `petgraph::stable_graph::Neighbors`, found reference
   |
   = note: expected enum `std::result::Result<petgraph::stable_graph::Neighbors<'static, Bar>, std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error>>`
              found enum `std::result::Result<&_, _>`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0271`.
error: could not compile `playground`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Comment: Your function is defined as returning a non-ref Neighbors (embedded inside a lock gusrd embedded inside a Result) isn't it?

Comment: @harmic it is, but Neighbors contains a ref that depends on world, so I'm not sure how to correct it

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, why are you using `try_map` and returning a `Result`?

Comment: Also to answer your question, it seems that this is currently a [missing feature](https://github.com/Kimundi/owning-ref-rs/issues/59), and it seems to me that `owning_ref` is likely not actively maintained.

Comment: Also note: https://github.com/Kimundi/owning-ref-rs/blob/677c5bbe33210e65ababfd46eeb2b7aaab41f94d/src/lib.rs#L1161-L1163

Comment: @Coder-256 using result is a artifact of trimming down from the larger real code base situation this is taken from :) In the real situation the code inside the closure can fail.

Comment: @Coder-256: I'm lost enough in the types I'm not sure what that feature does or how it helps. Could you expand a little bit? Maybe I can figure out how to jigger it if I understand.

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but AFAIK there's just no way to do this safely as of today. The problem is that `OwningRef` only works with references. `OwningHandle` is meant to work with smart pointers, but it currently only supports `RefCell`. It looks like `RwLock` support was planned, but it's hard to tell if that's still the case, or even if the crate is still well-maintained.

Comment: And I am unaware of any alternative crates. One solution could be to implement this yourself ([ex. `RefCell`](https://github.com/Kimundi/owning-ref-rs/blob/677c5bbe33210e65ababfd46eeb2b7aaab41f94d/src/lib.rs#L1151-L1159)) but I'm not 100% sure if that's safe or even the right solution in your case.

Comment: [`rental`](https://crates.io/crates/rental) would solve your problem, but it is [no longer supported](https://github.com/jpernst/rental). Personally I'm not sure what the best solution is here.